# Search in multiple array with Python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, search, fft

I have 2 large arrays, their length is 220500 . First one contains frequencies and second one contains corresponding amplitudes. In frequency array, I'm looking for a certain frequency (if I'm looking for 2084 Hz, my array has 5 of it with different floats, check output) and when I find, I'm checking the exact index in amplitude array and if amplitude is higher than a threshold, I'm saving it. As you understand, with my basic knowledge this process takes some time. I wrote my code and looking for a performance improvement.

```
for a in range(len(freqs_side)):
    if int(freqs_side[a])==2084 and FFT_side[a]>=400000000000:
        print(freqs_side[a],FFT_side[a])
        cm2084 = FFT_side[a]
    if int(freqs_side[a])==4168 and FFT_side[a]>=5400000000:
        print(freqs_side[a],FFT_side[a])
        cm4168 = FFT_side[a]
    if int(freqs_side[a])==6253 and FFT_side[a]>=9000000000:
        print(freqs_side[a],FFT_side[a])
        cm6253 = FFT_side[a]
print(cm2084,cm4168,cm6253)
```

Output:

```
2084.0 2868277384164.6855
2084.2000000000003 572554922314.2518
2084.4 3071644765158.3857
2084.6 975955084258.288
2084.8 2796994096747.6177
4168.0 33732728471.680416
4168.2 15743047559.956854
4168.400000000001 44461000497.85484
4168.6 26685518022.139732
4168.8 46429822807.83282
6253.0 18624382300.312286
6253.200000000001 16881233499.987783
6253.400000000001 19866071791.015427
6253.6 11578917518.428934
6253.8 17286682318.312145
2796994096747.6177 46429822807.83282 17286682318.312145
```

Comment: You  mention a FFT, is it possible that you are using Numpy?

Comment: is `freqs_side` sorted? If so I would suggest using bisect https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html

Comment: As it reads your code saves the last 3 FFT values matching the given freqs. In this case scanning backwards and exiting early could save some iterations.

Comment: Are you reusing the same arrays each time and looking at various frequencies and amplitude thresholds (that's how your question reads to me)? If so you can do it very fast if you make the appropriate dict the first time round.

Comment: I would use np.where() for this.

Comment: Yes, I am dealing with numpy arrays @gboffi

Comment: @PawełKordowski   Yes, It is sorted but as you see my search results with multiple output (2084.0 2084.2....). I pick the biggest integer between these same freqs. I will check that thanks